# Will I have problems if I publish an app with a packagename different of bundle id?

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-play, app-store

Recently I had to change the package name of my android project because I had to disable an old app to change some pieces of information and some of the UI of it. But the business logic are pretty the same. So I wonder, can I use the same solution with a different package name for Android (for create another app in google play with the same name but different package name) and then keep the bundle id the same for iOS to not have to recreate another one in the app store? Will I have problems with it?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my knowledge, there should not be any issues if you make sure about the following pointers:

- Everything that was registered on the old bundle id is now registered for the new one and replaced with the new one all over your project. eg: if you have a firebase product used then you replace the old `googleservices.json` with the new one.
- The old app that you have on the store is removed(To avoid confusion for users)
- You can use the same key to sign the key but you cannot use the same App that you added on store earlier.
- Make sure you do not have any dependency of any sort on the old bundle id.

**Note:** Your old app will not be replaced by this new one even though they would have the same name as the bundle id is the unique identifier for this.

There should not be any problems if you use the same bundle id for the new iOS app as you had earlier but usually, both apps have the same bundle just to keep it standard. But you can always opt. not to.

Goodluck feel free to get back if you have any more queries

Comment: Thanks for the answer @FreakyAli! This answered my question.

Comment: If so please mark it correct for others to find out